# How to search not same images but similar images by pyautogui

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui

I use pyautogui to search an image on Desktop window for click automation.

> pyautogui.locateOnScreen(image)

If the image is captured on the same screen as screenshot, it can be matched. However, if the image is a bit different, it cannot. e.g. captured as the low resolution image.
Can I set some likelihood in pyautogui or use other library?

Answer (score 0):

Use confidence, default value is 0.999. Reason is pyscreeze is actually used by pyautogui which has the confidence value which most likely represents a percentage from 0% - 100% for a similarity match. Looking through the code with my amateur eyes reveals that OpenCV and NumPy are required for confidence to work otherwise a different function would be used that doesn't have the confidence value.

for example:

`pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('foo.png', confidence=0.5)`
will set your confidence to 0.5, which means 50%.